# Javascript array push function

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

I have created a form in html which takes in user data. And then I use javascript to save that data into an array. Below is my code:

```
  function test(){
     var fName =  document.getElementById('myName').value;

       var test = ["dataOne"];
        test.push("dataTwo");
        test.push("dataThree");

        test.push(fName);
        }
```

THE ISSUE:
DataOne, dataTwo and dataThree are held at the following indexes in the array 0,1,2. Now the data being entered by the user through the form is being saved into a variable called "fName" and then that variable is being pushed into the array.

When I push the variable into the array its held at index 3 in the array. Every time a user inputs some data the data is saved at index 3. I wanted the next data to be saved at index 4 and the index 5 and so on. Every user submission should be at a new index. Currently if a user submits a form the array will look like this:

User 1:

[dataOne,dataTwo, dataThree,user1 input]

If a 2nd user submits a form:

User 2:

[dataOne,dataTwo, dataThree,user2 input]

The user1 input has been over written by the user 2 input.

Can anyone help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your title really has little to do with the actual question.

Comment: when do you call test function?

Comment: You've already asked this question… and this version has even less information about what you mean by "submit the form" than the first one did.

Comment: @Alper Cinar the test fuction is called when the user clicks on the submit button on a html form.

Comment: @user2190986 — Look at what the test function does. Think about what it means to do the things it does *every* time the submit button is clicked. Think about **when** you want to *create the array* and when you want to *add items to the array*.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're redeclaring/overwriting the array every time the function is called. Try something like this:

```
var test = ["dataOne"]; //\
test.push("dataTwo");   //>which equals var test = ["dataOne", "dataTwo", "dataThree"]
test.push("dataThree"); ///

function func(){
    var fName =  document.getElementById('myName').value;
    test.push(fName);
}
```

That way every new function call with push another string to the array.

Also note you I had to change the function name because not everything can be called `test` (the array and the function).